# Viewing TFVC repository contents as of a specific date

Tags: tfs, tfvc

I want to get the state of a repository as of a given date, view the files and then subsequently view the history of those files independently in Team Foundation Version Control (TFVC).

I know I can "Get this Version", but that's not what I want. I'm not looking to change my local system or download and change my working directories contents. Even if I do a "Get this Version" and view the contents of a file that exists which was replaced later down the line with a file of the same name (a "Delete" followed by an "Add" in a different commit), the history of the file I'm attempting to view seems to only follow the ancestry of the most recent file, not the older one in question.

Ex:

1. Feb: `ADD` `Repo\MyFile.cs`
2. March `MODIFY` `Repo\MyFile.cs`
3. April: `DELETE` `Repo\MyFile.cs`
4. May: `ADD` `Repo\MyFile.cs`
5. June: `MODIFY` `Repo\MyFile.cs`

If I do a "`Get This Version`" at revision #2 and then, after getting that version, find the file `MyFile.cs` in my project attempt to view the history of the file, I only see history from revisions #4 and #5. I want to be able to get insight into revisions #1 - #3 and see that ancestry clearly.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Hi Ryan which version control are you talking about, TFVC or Git? Sorry not totally get your point about this part `the history of the file I'm attempting to view seems to only follow the ancestry of the most recent file, not the older one in question.` Could you explain more clearly?

Comment: Hi @PatrickLu-MSFT, please see my revised question and let me know if I can elaborate further. Thank you.